# How can I extend a horizontal line to the edge of the page container?

Tags: html, css

I want to have a heading which looks like this:

```
HEADING -----------------------------------
```

with the line extending to the edge of the container in a responsive  manner.

I created a basic version with the css  below, which specifies a percentage length for the line, but I can't figure out how to extend the line specifically to the container edge.

```
.border-heading {
     clear: both;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: left;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 3%;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
    color: #bf593a;
     font-family: "Sorts Mill Goudy", serif;

}

@media (max-width: 767px)
    {.border-heading 
{font-size: 40px;
    }
}


.border-heading:after {
    content: '';
    height: 3px; /* Change border thickness */
    background-color: #bf593a; /* Change border color */
    flex: 0 0 50%; /* 20% is the border width */
    margin: 0 30px;
}
```

Here is the page in question. Please scroll down to "Photo Galleries" and "Blog Posts".

https://theslowroad.org/category/destinations/asia/cambodia/

Comment: Can't help with this question but in your body CSS tag turn off your horizontal overflow.

Comment: `flex-grow: 1` instead of `flex: 0 0 50%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `flex:1`

```css
.border-heading {
  clear: both;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 3%;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
  color: #bf593a;
  font-family: "Sorts Mill Goudy", serif;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .border-heading {
    font-size: 40px;
  }
}

.border-heading:after {
  content: '';
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #bf593a;
  flex: 1;               /* Change this */  
  margin: 0 30px;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="border-heading">
  Photo Galleries
</h2>
```